Example of a parametric curve with $r'(t)$ not continuous but $r'(t)\neq0$ at a point $t_0$.
Can you give me an example of a parametric curve $r(t)=(x(t), y(t))$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which satisfies the following properties:
$r'(t_0)\neq 0$ for some point $t_0$ and $r'(t)$ is not continuous at this point $t_0$.
I would like to plot the parametric curve and see why both the conditions $r'(t_0)\neq 0$ and $r'(t)$ being continuous are both essential to say the curve is smooth at $t_0$.

Let $r_1(t)=t^2\sin(1/t)+t$ for $t\neq 0$, and $r_1(t)=0$ for $t=0$. Also, let $r_2(t)=t^2$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ ($g$ can be any smooth function). Now, of course, let $r(t)=(r_1(t),r_2(t))$. Note that the derivative of $r_1(t)$ exists everywhere (you should verify that $r_1’(0)=1$), but it is discontinuous at $t_0=0$. So $r’(t)$ is discontinuous at $t_0=0$, but $r’(t_0)\neq 0$.
The much more interesting case is when $r’(t_0)=0$ for some $t_0$, and $r’$ is continuous everywhere. There’s a very nice reason for why we can’t include this case in the definition of ‘smooth’. Let $r_1(t)=0$ for $t\leq 0$, and $r_1(t)=e^{-1/t^2}$ for $t>0$, and $r_2(t)=t^2$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.
Plotting these should clarify things.
I’d also like to remind you to show your work whenever asking a question.
